# free() function always crash

Tags: memory-management, linked-list, malloc, free

so, all my work just fine, but only the free function is disable
i'm pretty sure that's the problem is in the way i'm using malloc

```
// This is the head 

typedef struct Contact {
    char*firstName;
    char* lastName;
    char* phoneNum;
    struct Contact* next
} Contact;
```

//this is how I allocate and create new contact
Just example for how I try to allocate using malloc

```
Contact* createNewCont(char* fName, char* lName, char* phoNum)
{
    Contact* newCont;
    newCont = malloc(sizeof (newCont));

    //allocate and check all the string in the contact
    newCont->firstName = malloc(strlen(fName));
    printf ("%d",strlen(fName));
    if(newCont->firstName == NULL)
        return NULL;
    strcpy(newCont->firstName,fName);

}
```

here the problem happend
I try to free specifc contact

```
int freeParam(Contact** head,char* fName, char* lName)
{
    Contact* temp = *head;
    int isExist = FALSE;
    int compVal1, compVal2;

    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("null");
        return FALSE;
    }
    compVal1 = strcmp((*head)->firstName,fName);
    compVal2 = strcmp((*head)->lastName,lName);
    if (compVal1 == 0 && compVal2 == 0)
    {
        if (temp->next == NULL)
        {
            Contact* toRemvoe = *head;
            *head = NULL;
            return TRUE;
        }
        Contact* toRemvoe = *head;
        (*head) = (*head)->next;

        free(toRemvoe->firstName);
        free(toRemvoe->lastName);
        free(toRemvoe->phoneNum);
        free(toRemvoe);
        toRemvoe = NULL;
        return TRUE;
    }
```

I saw some answers but didnt understand much

I try few diffrent ways, to allocate using malloc
but I got the same result

Comment: If not sure always reference the documentation to learn the return value and the parameters to the function. So, malloc, returns void * and has parameters of amount of memory to allocate (allocate a little more than need and verify boundary of src), in your case number of characters (strlen(fName)) * size of char (or int ...),  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/malloc.html  --- https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/  -- provide more of the code what's **head

Comment: thank you! I added the missing part (I hope)
I you can I take a look please :)

Comment: *which* `free` call produces an error?

Comment: hey! thank u for your helping, I found the problem
I allocate the Contact with mallox (sizeof (Contact *))
insted mallox (sizeof (Contact))